# Android Firebase Database called from inside another: retrieve which data first

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
// First call
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/randomUserId")
    .addValueEventListener() { ... };

// Second call
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("node/randomNodeId")
    .addValueEventListener() { ... };
```

I've understand that code above will be called by order: first until finished, then second. But what if I add third call inside event of first call like this:

```
// First call
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/randomUserId")
    .addValueEventListener() {
        ...
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Third call
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("anotherNode/anotherRandomNodeId")
                .addValueEventListener() { ... };
        }
        ...
    };

// Second call
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("node/randomNodeId")
    .addValueEventListener() { ... };
```

If it's like that, what are the orders? Is it `first -> second -> third` because the second call will be read earlier than the third. Or will it be `first -> third -> second` because the second call wait for the first call to be finished (and first call need the third call to be finished so it consider itself finished). Or like what?

And is `addValueEventListener` and `addChildEventListener` has different priority?

Note: I use this logic to determine if my call completely finished (first time). If there is better way to do it, your answer is welcome. But I still really need to know this. (Like you, I hate not knowing what I do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely outcome of your last snippets is:

> First result
>
> Second result
>
> Third result

The reason for this is that you don't register your third listener, until the first result is back. It is *extremely* likely that this won't happen before the second listener is registered.

But it's not a hard guarantee. The only guarantee you have with this code is that the third result will come after the first result.

Comment: Thank you very much. And did `addValueEventListener` and `addChildEventListener` have different priority in this matter?

Comment: I think I can't use this logic to determine if my call completely finished for first time. I might figure out some other way tho, thank you

Comment: If you register a value listener and a child listener on the same location/query, the data will be synchronized from the server only once. The client/SDK will then fire the child events in order first and then the value event after that.